# Image Injected to Wrong Table Cell in MSWord

Tags: vb.net, ms-word

I'm trying to create a table with images in it in Microsoft Word. All of the images get placed in cell [1,1]. I've tried working this a couple different ways. Any ideas on how to get my second image placed in cell [1,2]?

```
    oTable3 = oDoc.Tables.Add(oDoc.Bookmarks.Item("\endofdoc").Range, 1, 2)
    oTable3.Range.Borders.OutsideLineStyle = Word.WdLineStyle.wdLineStyleNone
    oTable3.Range.Borders.InsideLineStyle = Word.WdLineStyle.wdLineStyleNone
    oTable3.Range.ParagraphFormat.SpaceAfter = 0
    oTable3.Range.ParagraphFormat.LineSpacingRule = Word.WdLineSpacing.wdLineSpaceSingle
    oTable3.Cell(1, 1).Range.Select()
    oWord.Selection.InlineShapes.AddPicture(FileName:=BPOCompSelector.FolderBrowserDialog1.SelectedPath & "\SUB1.jpg", LinkToFile:=False, SaveWithDocument:=True)
    oTable3.Cell(1, 2).Range.Select()
    'oTable3.Rows(1).Cells(2).Select()
    oWord.Selection.InlineShapes.AddPicture(FileName:=BPOCompSelector.FolderBrowserDialog1.SelectedPath & "\SUB2.jpg", LinkToFile:=False, SaveWithDocument:=True)
```

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nevermind, I figured it out.
I added a nothing action line after it Selects the second cell:

```
    oTable3.Cell(2, 2).Range.Select()
    oWord.Selection.TypeText("")
```